# Spring Core Framework - Where are the beans hold?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am a junior Java developer and I am reading the spring documentation from [spring.io](http://spring.io). I read that every bean that gets registered in the `*.xml` file that spring uses to resolve dependencies is declared using `<bean> </bean>` tags.

My question is: In which data structure are the beans hold after the xml file is read and the beans are instantiated(created)?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by data structures? Are you looking to learn about the internals of Spring or the way that you will be able to access the beans?

Comment: It's in bean factory.

Comment: It's just a curiosity!

Answer (score 14):

Although you should not be worried much about the internal structures if you are just beginning to learn [Spring](http://spring.io/) but for the sake of knowledge in almost all cases the underlying class is [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.html) and as you can see by going through the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java) it maintains a ConcurrentHashMap of singleton objects. Also there are similar other map object for other information being stored.

```
private final Map<String, Object> singletonObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>(64);
```

Comment: Thank you @Shailendra! Just the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as a `Map` where the keys are bean ids and the values are actual Objects.