# Where is spring context stored and what is the data structure?

Tags: spring, spring-context

Where is spring context stored? In which data structure? ( I heard it's just a Map, is it?)
( I don't mean the path to the xml file, I mean when Spring read bean definitions it stored the information about it somewhere and injects it)

Comment: possible reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565706/spring-core-framework-where-are-the-beans-hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry

private final Map<String, Object> singletonObjects = new ConcurrentHashMap(256);
```

Singleton beans are stored here.